# iPhone - Wheel tracking finger jumps to same starting position?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to implement a selection wheel in an iphone application. I have got the wheel to track the users finger but now for some reason when the user touches the screen the wheel jumps so the same section of the wheel tracks the finger each time.

How would I get it so the wheel rotates like the user is dragging it from any point?

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

int tInput = [allTouches count]-1;

UITouch *touch =[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:tInput];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
float theAngle = atan2( location.y-imageX.center.y, location.x-imageX.center.x );

CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(theAngle);
imageX.transform = cgaRotate;
```

}

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right - that makes perfect sense - this is indeed what your code does.

What you need to add is the initial value where you started your drag as a relative rotation -- or track your last rotation.

A very elaborate way is shown below - but this should help get the point across.

```
@interface UntitledViewController : UIViewController {
        CGPoint firstLoc;
        UILabel * fred;
        double angle;
}
@property (assign) CGPoint firstLoc;
@property (retain) UILabel * fred;

@implementation UntitledViewController
@synthesize fred,firstLoc;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fred = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
    fred.text = @"Fred!"; fred.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:fred];

    angle = 0; // we aint have rotated just yet...
};

// make sure we get them drag events.
- (BOOL)isFirstResponder { return YES; } 

-(void)handleObject:(NSSet *)touches 
          withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
             isLast:(BOOL)lst 
{
    UITouch *touch =[[[event allTouches] allObjects] lastObject];
    CGPoint curLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    float fromAngle = atan2( firstLoc.y-fred.center.y, 
                             firstLoc.x-fred.center.x );
    float toAngle = atan2( curLoc.y-fred.center.y, 
                           curLoc.x-fred.center.x );

    // So the angle to rotate to is relative to our current angle and the
    // angle through which our finger moved (to-from)
    float newAngle = angle + (toAngle - fromAngle);

    CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle);
    fred.transform = cgaRotate;

    // we only 'save' the current angle when we're done with the drag.
    //
    if (lst)
        angle = newAngle;
    }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch =[[[event allTouches] allObjects] lastObject];

    // capture where we started - so we can later work out the 
    // rotation relative to this point.
    //
    firstLoc = [touch locationInView:self.view];
};


-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self handleObject:touches withEvent:event isLast:NO];
};

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self handleObject:touches withEvent:event isLast:YES];
}
```

Obviously you can do this a lot more elegant - and above misses a bit of 0 .. 2xPI capping you need.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but I have one more little thing using this method seems to stop me being able to detect touches within the UIImageView (the Circle)? 
In the touches began method I add this code to capture the touch location and compare to my imageView, but it does not seem to trigger?

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view.superview];
 
if ([touch view] == imageOne) {
 imageHolder= coinOne;
}

any suggestions as to why this is?

Comment: Aye - just disable user interaction at all other views - so all interaction is seen by whichever UIView you do the above drag detection on.

Comment: You have been sooo much help! Thank you so much! I have one very last question if it's not too much trouble? How do I now find a point of alignment on my rotating circle?  for example if I put an image of an arrow above my circle and I rotate it how would I be able to extract the point it stops rotating at? kind of like a wheel of fortune lol

Comment: Aye - in above example - the variable 'angle' contains the absolute rotation of your wheel. So if you want to tell soemthing about that you would change 

    if (lst)
        angle = newAngle;

into something like 

    if (lst) {
        angle = newAngle;
        [someone tellAboutNewOrientation:angle];
    }

Comment: thank you Dirk! Its guys like you that make stackoverflow a better place for noobs like me

Answer (score 0):

Because the view itself is still the old one. You may want to fetch the zip example file in:

```
 http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=77
```

and in PuttyView.m change the:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
....  
else {
   self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,
                          self.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
```

into

```
else {
   NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

   int tInput = [allTouches count]-1;

   UITouch *touch =[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:tInput];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
   float theAngle = atan2( location.y-self.center.y, location.x-self.center.x );

   CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(theAngle);
   self.transform = cgaRotate;
```

}

where you thus stay within the view and its relative angle. Alternatively - in your code - keep the relative angle itself.

Comment: what you have suggested does not work if anything it breaks the 1 to 1 tracking of the users touch input as the object rotates at a smaller amount of radians. Once past a certain point of rotation the object flips to align to a different point.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the first point. The latter point is indeed correct - atan2() with this delta which give you the smallest rotation under which the object needs to rotate to align with that vector - hence the flipping.

Comment: the first point is the original code I supply already tracks the finger well, but when the user places his finger on the screen the image will auto align so that the 90degree point on the image is the fixed point that tracks the finger.
Implementing your code makes it so that when tracking the users finger for every full rotation the users finger completes the image has only rotated about 3/5 of a rotation? as well as the flipping...

Comment: I'm not always the best with words so I tried making a quick video, I have tried to show what happens with my code and the code you suggested. I hope this sorta helps show what I mean. Any help would be amazing. Thanks 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PC6--zrXLk