# UIImageView how to track clockwise or counterclockwise user motion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have successfully implemented rotating a uiimageview using this code from this post

[iPhone - Wheel tracking finger jumps to same starting position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188744/iphone-wheel-tracking-finger-jumps-to-same-starting-position/4209190#comment13012666_4209190)

My question to fellow developers is that the user on touch can rotate the image both clockwise and counterclockwise. Is there a way I can detect in which direction is the user moving the view?

Its important to me because I am making a clock app. I let users move the min hand form 0 min all the way to 60 min. When it reaches there I move the hour hand one up. But the user can spin the min hand counter clockwise in which case I need to move the hour hand one down. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't read that post carefully, but I notice that the accepted answer computes a fromAngle and toAngle.  The sign of the difference of those seems to be what you need.

Comment: That doesn't work. In a circle you cannot depend on angles to see which direction the object is rotating, meaning if I rotate an object from sitting at 270 degrees to 270 degrees how in the world do I know which way I rotated the object?!

Answer (score 3):

you can set a member variable named "lastPoint" to record the point last time you moved

the you can calc the direction next time

```
CGPoint lastPoint;


- (void) touchedBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

//you can save the point , then used in next time you want

int tInput = [allTouches count]-1;

UITouch *touch =[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:tInput];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
float theAngle = atan2( location.y-imageX.center.y, location.x-imageX.center.x );

float theLastAngle =  atan2( lastPoint.y-imageX.center.y, lastPoint.x-imageX.center.x );

lastPoint = location;

// compare theAngle & theLastAngle , so you can know it is clockwise or counterclockwise.
}
```

Comment: @SamBudda: if you figured this on your own it would be fair to communicty if you post your answer. It is also a good practice to at least upvote a good answer if you choose not to accept it. +1 from me to adali.